# Is it possible to make a hireling consume tadpoles?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

One of my party members is a hireling. Is there a way to make them consume tadpoles, and more importantly, convince them to use

> the astral tadpole and become half-illithid?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. They dont't have a tadpole in their brain since they were not on the nautiloid. Same applies to some followers you aquire later in game. If a character doesn't have a tadpole (so they are not a true soul) they can't use tadpoles.